# Ajax File Uploader .Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've found plenty of links for a file up loader like this one [here][1]

But they all require a php file to move the file. What i want is to use ajax to pass the file to an asp handler or even to a web service so that i can then encode it to a byte[] and insert it into a database.

Anyone with any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is convert the php code to .net.  If you don't know php, just pull up the php code and go to php.net and look up what those function calls do.  Then come back here with any specific questions you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [jquery.form.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin to upload large files to server in ASP.NET.

**FileUpload.aspx**

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        form#upForm
        {
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto;
            background: #eee;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .progress
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 1px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .bar
        {
            background-color: #B4F5B4;
            width: 0%;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .percent
        {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            top: 3px;
            left: 48%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Uploading</h3>

    <form id="upForm" action="UploadHandler.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server" />
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>
        (function () {

            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            var status = $('#status');

            if ($.browser.msie ||
                ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version.slice(0, 3) < 2))
                $(".progress").hide();

            $('form#upForm').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                    if ($.browser.msie ||
                        ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version.slice(0, 1) < 2))
                        status.html("uploading....");
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                },
                resetForm: true

            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UploadHandler.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public partial class UploadHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[0];

        string filename = hpf.FileName;
        string folderLoc = @"d:\foldername";

        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            hpf.SaveAs((folderLoc) + @"\" + filename);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
        Response.Write("The file " + filename + " is successfully uploaded");
    }
}
```

some points to be noted:

- I faced some problem when i tried to make `FileUpload.aspx` inherit from a MasterPage.
- You might use the same `Fileupload.aspx` pages code behind instead of using a separate `Uploadhandler.aspx` file. I haven't tried that, but i think it's possible.
- Instead of using a `aspx` page you can also try to use a `generic handler` page. Again, I haven't tried that but think might it's possible.
- you need to use jquery 1.8.3 or lower for this as `$.browser` is not available in upper versions. or you can edit the code to make it work with latest version of jquery.